# Retrieve Oracle database name without querying

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, conditional-compilation

I have two Oracle 11gR2 databases (one for testing purposes and the other is production).

By using conditional compilation I need to create a function that will use database link in test environment and will **not** use database link in production.

The problem is that I need to put that into package body which will be automatically compiled in both environments. There will be no such database link in production environment, therefore the package **will not compile**.

One solution would be to create a dummy database link which in production environment resolves to itself (production -> production), but that surely is not the right way to solve this problem.

For example:

```
DECLARE 
    v_db_name     VARCHAR2(200);
    vt_tbl_data   data_table%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    $IF v_db_name = 'TEST' $THEN 
        SELECT tbl.*
          INTO vt_tbl_data
          FROM data_table@otherdb tbl
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
    $ELSIF v_db_name = 'PROD' $THEN
        SELECT tbl.*
          INTO vt_tbl_data
          FROM data_table tbl
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
    $END
END;
/
```

Comment: How does the automatic compilation occur - do you have the ability to alter the session the compilation happens in? (Presumably the schema names are the same - otherwise you could check that more easily...)

Comment: `PLSQL_CCFLAGS` can be used. You can do `ALTER SYSTEM SET PLSQL_CCFLAGS = 'env_test:true';` on testing database, and then use `$IF $$env_test  $THEN  xxxxxx $ELSE yyyyyy $END`. Please see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#BABIHIHF) for details. However I like the idea with synonym the most.

Comment: No, I'm unable to change the compilation sequence and alter the session. However, thanks to both of you for your comments. Didn't know about PLSQL_CCFLAGS until now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't have the database link syntax in your package body. Create a synonym in both environments and reference the synonym in your package body.

That way your package bodies are the same in both environments - only the definition of the synonyms are different.

Answer (score 2):

If you can alter the compilation session - in either or both environments - you could use [a compilation flag via `PLSQL_CCFLAGS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-623713EB-4FD1-4C8B-955C-4135342F5F68):

```
alter session set PLSQL_CCFLAGS = 'has_db_link:TRUE';

DECLARE 
    vt_tbl_data   data_table%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    $IF $$has_db_link $THEN 
        SELECT tbl.*
          INTO vt_tbl_data
          FROM data_table@otherdb tbl
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
    $ELSE
        SELECT tbl.*
          INTO vt_tbl_data
          FROM data_table tbl
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
    $END
END;
/
```

or with less repetition, but maybe harder to follow:

```
DECLARE 
    vt_tbl_data   data_table%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT tbl.*
      INTO vt_tbl_data
    $IF $$has_db_link $THEN 
      FROM data_table@otherdb tbl
    $ELSE
      FROM data_table tbl
    $END
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
END;
/
```

If you set the flag to `FALSE`, or don't set it at all, in production then it will only compile the `$ELSE` branch.

You can't set the flag to a string, so you can't test for a specific name; but true/false seems more intuitive to me anyway.

If you can't change how the compilation happens in order to alter the session, you could potentially do that via a logon trigger - perhaps only in the test environment in that case, and maybe with a more general flag name like `env_test` as @krokodilko suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I am unable to change how the compilation happens. I'm sure your answer could help some other folks, too.